# Add an icon to a new file extension using install4j

Tags: file, icons, install4j

How can I give an icon for the new file extension using install4j while creating installer for my java application. I already know how give an icon for the my application. Now I want to know how to give an icon for new file extensions which is created by my application.

Answer (score 0):

The "Create a file association" action has two properties for that: "Icon file for Windows" and "Icon file for Mac OS X".